# Azure Table Storage: Same Query on Same Data returns different results

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

**Background Information:**

1. Using Azure Table Storage (not SQL Azure)
2. I have a table called Reservations with a PK: Int (Id of Person/Organization making Reservation); RK: String (format of -)
3. The query that is seen below does a compare (RowKey >= EntityName and RowKey <= EntityNamea) so that we can get all rows that have a RowKey of a specific entity type as character "a" is less than "-" in ASCII
4. I'm running reports on reservations that have happened and reservations that are upcoming for different date ranges along with some other criteria based on other attributes.
5. The table consists of roughly 5k-10k records

**Query on Azure taken from Fiddler:**

`https://<domain>.table.core.windows.net/ReservationEntity()?$filter=(((((RowKey%20ge%20'ReservationEntity')%20and%20(RowKey%20lt%20'ReservationEntitya'))%20and%20(StartTime%20ge%20datetime'2013-07-31T00%3A00%3A00'))%20and%20(StartTime%20le%20datetime'2013-09-01T23%3A59%3A59'))%20and%20(Status%20eq%20'Pending'))%20and%20(PartyId%20eq%204)`

**My Question:**

I run this query multiple times against the same table which contains the same data.  The table has at least 5k records and no more than 10k records as listed above.  When I run this query I get the following results: 12, 19, 35, 35...and then it stays at 35 which is the correct amount. Is there something that I'm not understanding about TableStorage for this to be happening?  Are there any particular settings that I need to be paying attention to?

Comment: How long do the queries take? Could they be timing out?

Comment: See if you're getting `x-ms-NextPartitionKey` and `x-ms-NextRowKey` headers in the response. Since you're not using PartitionKey in your query, your query is performing full table scan and is returning only a subset of data. Please note that in a single request to table service, table service will only return a maximum of 1000 entities.

Comment: @GauravMantri looks like you are right.  I'm seeing "x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey" and "x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey".  Maybe I read the documentation wrong, but I was under the impression that I would only get these headers if my actual results (so the 35 that I am expecting) was greater than 1000. Are you able to explain why this is in more detail or point me in the right direction? Thanks again!

Comment: Gaurav is correct.  You can also see continuation tokens if your query crosses a partition boundary.  Meaning, if your 35 rows happened to be split between two partitions you may get a subset of the 35 in the first call, and the rest in the second.  If your data is split across more partitions then you may have to do more calls until all data is loaded. Table Storage is also analyzing partition usage and juggling data in the background so you'll see different subsets returned as that happens as well. Always look for continuation tokens.